# possible to create 3D lighting effect with CSS?

Tags: css

Here's an image I'd like to recreate with HTML/CSS:

[image]

The center gradient is easy enough, as are the two rings (a border around the center, and a div around that div that has its own border). The outside shadow on the left seems simple enough as well.

Here's my best approximation so far ([with a matching fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/jwPa3/)):

```
  <div id="youedge">
    <div id="youlight" class="round border radialgradientbg">                
    </div>
  </div>

#youedge {
    border:30px solid #888;
    border-radius:190px;
    width:190px;height:190px;margin:50px;
    box-shadow:-30px 0 0 #555;
}

    #youlight { width:150px; height:150px; background-color:#2b0c0f; }
    .round { border-radius:190px; }
    .border { border:20px solid #777; }
    body { background-color:#999; }

    .radialgradientbg {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #4c1113 0%, #16040a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#4c1113), color-stop(100%,#16040a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #4c1113 0%,#16040a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    }
```

What I can't figure out is the 3D lighting effects on the two gray borders around the center. Is there a way to accomplish this in CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it with a single element and using `:before` and `:after` along with `linear-gradient` and `box-shadow`..

The idea is to put two circles behind the main element with opposite linear gradient backgrounds..

```css
.circle-3d {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:2em;
}

.circle-3d:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #666, #ccc);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -2;
  box-shadow: -20px 0 10px -5px #000;
}

.circle-3d:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #222, #eee);
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-3d"></div>
```

Comment: nice. i added the radial gradient center and tweaked sizes. it's a very close match now. http://dabblet.com/gist/7397257